# Ubuntu doesn't recognize USB device

Tags: usb

I have an external USB network adapter (Edimax) which is not recognized after I plug into my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. First of all I ask ubuntu to list me all USB devices by `lsusb`it shows all connected devices (and even more, this laptop has only two USB ports but lsusb prints 5 records why is that?) beside that network adapter. When I unplug it and plug again `dmesg` also doesn't metion it at all.
The adapter itself works properly on other laptop with windows, the usb port is also OK since other devices work OK. So what is the problem?

PS: I also have to add that at work I have the exact same adapter (in terms of model and producer) and that one works OK.

Answer (score 0):

If the USB works fine elsewhere, then it’s usually a driver. You can try tail -f /var/log/syslog then insert the USB and see if Ubuntu even attempts to read it. 
Each manufacturer can create a driver for Linux. If they don’t then the community would do it. This can take time. And I guess no guarantee that someone actually will create a driver for it..